# Count how many TVP,SAC,ACR,CFA in front of 7503054645,7503053801,8285090082,8285283074

Tags: excel

What is the best way to count how many instances of TVP, SAC, ACR or CFA are in front of any number? Below is an example of what I have:

```
Number          STAGE
    7503054645  SAC
    7503054645  SAC
    7503054645  CFA
    7503053801  SAC
    8285283073  SAC
    8285090082  SAC
    8285090082  SAC
    8285090082  SAC
    8285090082  SAC
    8285283074  TVP
    8285090078  TVP
    8285090078  CFA
    8285090078  SAC
    8285090081  SAC
    8285090081  SAC
    8285090081  SAC
    8285090081  SAC
    7503053801  SAC
    7503053801  CFA
    8285590611  SAC
    7503054645  SAC
    7503054645  CFA
    8285590611  TVP
    8285590611  TVP
    8285590611  TVP
    8285590611  TVP
```

Expected output:

```
Number     sac acr tvp cfa
7503054645 1 2 5  6
```

Comment: Can you format this so it's obvious it's meant to be a table please? Can you give us the sample output you want, e.g. a table with columns number, SAC count, TVP count, etc.? And can you tell us what you've tried already if possible too?

Comment: `=CountIf(B:B,"SAC")`

Comment: Question is not clear, can you add expected output? What do you mean by `in front of`?

Answer (score 3):

You could probably get the results you want by using a Pivot Table.  Drag Number to the Row Labels; STAGE to the Column Labels, and STAGE to the Values area.  Format to taste:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

ACR 10
CFA 78
OCP 3
SAC 959
SAP 8
STAGE   1
TVP 580

Sometimes it's best to use the right tool for the job.  ..Simple with a data base.  Suck into a table.  Sort and summarize by key, and count.

In Excel I imagine you could sort, and have an if for each type into a new column which puts a 1 in the column if TVP for example, and a 0 for anything else.  Then sum the column of 1's and zeros.

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
| 28388383 | SAC | if(b1 = 'SAC') then 1 else 0 
+-----------------------------------------------+
...
                               sum
```

Comment: .. but you changed your data on me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution without using Pivot. Enter below formula to `C2` and copy it to `C`,`D`, and `E` column cells.

`=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A2,$B:$B,C$1)`

[image]